# Functions for dynamic memory allocation in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to set up some generic functions in C++ to allocate memory dynamically, and this is what I got to so far:

```
char* init_char(uint64_t A, const char* init){
  char* ptr = new char[A];
  memset(ptr, '\0', A*sizeof(char));

  if(init != NULL)
    strcpy(ptr, init);

  return ptr;
}

char** init_char(uint64_t A, uint64_t B, const char* init){
  char** ptr = new char*[A];
  for(uint64_t a = 0; a < A; a++)
    ptr[a] = init_char(B, init);

  return ptr;
}
```

The idea is that you just pass the dimensions (A, B) and the initialization string (init) and it return an array with all the memory allocated. However, while the first one seems to work properly, the second one returns a NULL pointer.

I've looked around but no good. Actually in some other post ([Function for Dynamic Memory allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947016/function-for-dynamic-memory-allocation)) they seem to do something quite similar. Am I missing something here?

thanks,

Comment: Are you sure you're programming in C++? Where's the [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)? Where's the [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: What's wrong with `new` and/or (preferably) smart pointers like `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg that too.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `std::string` is too safe and boring. Here, you can use `strcpy` to write out of bounds, which is always cool.

Comment: How did you establish that it returns a NULL pointer?

Comment: Granted I could use std::string and std::vector, but I can't. I'm working on pre-existing code and that's how it's written.

Comment: In your example, you do not need to invoke sizeof(char), it does not cost anything, but it does not make any sense either. Actually you do not need to invoke memset at all because you are invoking strcpy later on.

Comment: @oopscene it is not guaranteed that char is one exactly byte, so using `sizeof(char)` is ok. better would be `sizeof(*ptr)` since you do not have to change two locations if the datatype of ptr changes.

Answer (score 4):

your error is not to use c++.

your problem can be reduced to:

```
std::string initStr("initialitation string");
int a = 10;

std::vector<std::string> myStringArray(a, initStr);
```

Comment: And here we go with vectors again. Vectors are not arrays. Try inserting 1 billion items in the vector (with the initial knowledge there's gonna be 1+ billion of items you want to insert). Good luck being time efficient.

Comment: Saraph, how is it going to be any less efficient than using a vector?

Comment: @Saraph if you know the length at compiletime you could use std::array (but the op dont know). if you know the size at runtime before all the inserts you can reserve the size in a single operation. and my example shows this. the constructer constructs a vector with the known size and fills it with the given value.  so all your critics are pointless

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit Do I really have to explain why? Haven't you ever compared arrays' performance to vectors? Vector is just not gonna replace array. If the realloc is done right, there is no reason in using vectors.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch "1+ billion", not "1 billion". Your answer is pointless, not my critics.

Comment: @Saraph please look at the ops code. this is exactly the same as the vector does. there is also no possibility to enlarge the the Array after initial givin A as length. the solutions are completely equivalent.